# ¿Visual Studio 2015 puede conectarse a un servidor de símbolos de Team Services?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsts

Estoy publicando paquetes NuGet de librerías de consumo interno en mi empresa a través de la extensión Package Management de Team Services.

Para permitir la depuración en estas librerías he activado la funcionalidad de servidor de símbolos (actualmente en preview).

Desde la build he publicado, aparentemente con éxito, los símbolos en el servidor. Sin embargo me he encontrado el problema a la hora de consumirlos.

En la documentación de Microsoft viene indicado que "funciona mejor" con Visual Studio 2017 Update 4 o posterior, y viene detallado como configurar Visual Studio 2017 para utilizar el servidor de símbolos.

Actualmente los equipos de desarrollo tienen Visual Studio 2015 y no he encontrado ningún sitio donde se indique cómo podría conectarse un Visual Studio 2015, ni he encontrado tampoco ningún sitio donde se indique que no se puede hacer.

¿Alguien sabe si existe alguna opción de configuración o alguna extensión para Visual Studio 2015 que permita hacerlo? ¿O si no se puede hacer?

Creía haberlo solucionado utilizando la url que aparece en la documentación para utilizar el servidor de símbolos desde WinDbg: [Add the symbol server to WinDbg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/symbols/debug-with-symbols-windbg#add-the-symbol-server-to-windbg)

Añadiendo en Visual Studio 2015 como el resto de servidores de símbolos (Herramientas -> Opciones -> Depuración -> Símbolos) utilizando la url:

```
https://<cuenta-team-services>.artifacts.visualstudio.com/_apis/symbol/symsrv
```

Pero parece que da problemas de autenticación:
En la carpeta configurada para almacenar la caché de símbolos en el equipo se genera el archivo pdb correspondiente, pero el contenido del pdb es código html de una página que trata de redireccionar a una web de login.

Comment: Has mirado si tienes activado en Herramientas/Opciones/Depuracion el check que dice "Habilitar ejecución paso a paso de código fuente de .net framework"? Por otro lado, en esa misma opción de Herramientas/Opciones/Depuracion, en Simbolos has añadido tu servidor?

Comment: El problema es que no tengo la url del servidor de símbolos. En VS 2017 hay una opción adicional para conectar a un servidor de Team Services en la que indicas la cuenta de Team Services. Pero en VS 2015 no existe la opción.

Comment: Pues no te puedo decir mas, yo no lo he probado. No se si has visto [este post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/15/vsts-is-now-a-symbol-server/). Tal vez preguntando ahi te den mas información, aunque solo habla de VS2017 Update 4 desde luego. Suerte

Comment: He probado con la url que se utiliza desde WinDbg pero, aunque en un primer momento parecía funcionar, no ha habido suerte.He ampliado la pregunta con info sobre la experiencia.